# how to increment value of a field by one in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to increment the value of a field by one whenever the function is called.But the problem is that it gets incremented by 3 instead of 1 though i have added +1.below is my code.

```
$this->loadModel('Listing');
$this->Listing->id = $listing_id;
$this->Listing->updateAll(array(
        'Listing.total_views' => 'Listing.total_views + 1'),
            array('Listing.id' => $listing_id));
```

Comment: This code for me works fine

Comment: Make sure the query is running only once. Check your sql dump.

Comment: @cartina:I have checked, this query is running only once.Is it possible that recursive can play any role in matter?

Comment: You can test using this $this->Listing->recursive = -1; before query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->loadModel('Listing');
$this->Listing->id = $listing_id;
$this->Listing->updateAll(array(
        'Listing.total_views' => 'Listing.total_views + 1'),
            array('Listing.id' => $listing_id));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It just changes the value to 0.

Comment: No need for `$this->Listing->id = $listing_id;`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It just changes the value to 0

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to update .It is better to fetch the total_views from database ,then increment it and update in database

```
$this->loadModel('Listing');
$this->Listing->id = $listing_id;
$count=$this->Listing->field('total_views');
$count=$count+1;
$this->Listing->saveField('Listing.total_views',$count);
```

If the problem continues ,then your code must be running multiple times.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a better way. What happens if a someone else views and this code is run while the orginal request is still running?Your method is not atomic